# Handling frequent schema change in the jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, moxy

In my application we are using JAXB for unmarshalling incoming xml response.
JAXB pojos are further mapped to DAOs for DB operations.

My issue is our service provider is going to frequently update their schema(xsd)(insertion, deletion of elements and attributes) and i dont want to keep generating POJOs for different versions of the same schema and updating my other codes.

Please suggest a solution to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into MOXy's Dynamic JAXB feature.  It allows you to bootstrap a JAXBContext directly from the schema, and interact with your model objects in a dynamic, schema-centric way.  Using this approach your application code would need to be updated to work with any new schema elements, but your JAXB binding code would stay the same.

Please see: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/dynamic_jaxb.htm#sthref191

Hope this helps,

Rick